# 'Use rollback executable' does not enforce setting an executable

Tags: install4j

Selecting `Use rollback executable` on an action does not enforce setting an executable. If the installation is cancelled after the action executes the installer fails with a `NullPointerException`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.misc.RunExecutableAction.maybeWithExtension(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.misc.RunExecutableAction.getUsedExecutable(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.misc.RunExecutableAction.runExecutable(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.misc.RunExecutableAction.rollback(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.InstallerContextImpl$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.actions.RunAction.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication.executeActionWrapper(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication$1.run(Unknown Source)
```

This seems pretty inconsistent. If the value is not nullable then it should be enforced on the IDE. If the value is nullable then the installer should `null` check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is enforced in the IDE when building the project. You can currently save the project in the incomplete state and use the command line compiler to get the above error.

The IDE should also validate these issues when saving. I've added this to the issue tracker.